# Configuring source map for React Native

Tags: android, react-native, source-maps

I'm trying to create a sourcemap for my RN app and this is my first time so please go easy on me.

I found a package [react-native-source-maps](https://github.com/philipshurpik/react-native-source-maps) that does this and I'm trying to understand how to move on with configuring Android side.

In the link mentioned that

```
def jsBundleMapFile = "${jsBundleFile}.map"

def devEnabled = !targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    commandLine("cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, "node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
            "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, "--sourcemap-output", jsBundleMapFile, *extraPackagerArgs)
} else {
    commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, "node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js", "bundle", "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
            "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, "--sourcemap-output", jsBundleMapFile, *extraPackagerArgs)
}
```

And below is the my react.gradle, which I'm not sure which part to paste the code in. The closest relevant part in `react.gradle` I believe is in below but not sure which part to place the above code and whether it will mess up the current gradle build

```
// Set up dev mode
  def devEnabled = !(config."devDisabledIn${targetName}"
                || targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release"))

  def extraArgs = extraPackagerArgs;

  if (bundleConfig) {
      extraArgs = extraArgs.clone()
      extraArgs.add("--config");
      extraArgs.add(bundleConfig);
  }

  if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    commandLine("cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath, bundleCommand, "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
                    "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, *extraArgs)
            } else {
    commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath, bundleCommand, "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
                    "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, *extraArgs)
  }

  enabled config."bundleIn${targetName}" ||
                config."bundleIn${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}" ?:
                targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
```